# Existence of strictly stationary and ergodic solution

Tags: markov-process, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

I am looking for a sufficient condition so that the following equation

$y_{t}=\alpha_{R_{t}}+\beta_{R_{t}}y_{t-1}+Q_{R_{t}}e_{t}$, where $R_{t}=1$, if $y_{t-1}\leq r_{1}$, $R_{t}=R_{t-1}$, if $r_{1}<y_{t-1}\leq r_{2}$, and $R_{t}=0$, if $y_{t-1}>r_{2}$,

admits a strictly stationary solution. The parameters $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are known and the process $\left(  e_{t}\right)  $ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with zero mean and unit variance. The distribution $f$ of $\left(  e_{t}\right)  $ is assumed to be strictly positive density function on the whole real line.

I think we can apply Brandt's Theorem [Brandt, A. (1986). The stochastic equation $Y_{n+ 1}= A_{n}Y_{n}+ B_{n}$ with stationary coefficients. Advances in Applied Probability, 18(1), 211-220] on the equivalent generalized AR representation of the previous equation

$ y_{t}= A_{t} y_{t-1} + B_{t}, $
where $A_{t}=\beta_{0}R_{t}+\beta_{1}\left(  1-R_{t}\right)  $ and
$B_{t}=\left(  \alpha_{0}+Q_{0}e_{t}\right)  R_{t}+\left(  \alpha_{1}%
+Q_{1}e_{t}\right)  \left(  1-R_{t}\right)  .$

I think we can apply Brand's Theorem (1986). It suffices to show that the bivariate process $(A_{t},B_{t})_{t}$ is strictly stationary and ergodic.
Is it possible to show this and how can I do it?